# Regex to get number from string

Tags: php, regex

Please help me to get number from following string...

> 755 North Estate, NY 11415 (QTY# 34255623)

I am trying to get `34255623` using regex but still learning the same, please any regex expert help me. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Ah, and what did you got?

Comment: It didnt work, sorry i am still learning regex, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/ <- Especially at the middle left character classes :)

Comment: Also check out https://regex101.com/, which will show you problems in your regex, what matches and why

Comment: yes thanks for docs, but if you provide an answer, that would help me to understand it better. I have just tried `/\(QTY\#\s\d/` but it didn't return number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
\(QTY\#\s(\d+)\)
```

Just use `\d` which is `0-9` with the quantifier `+` which means 1 or more times.

[<kbd>**regex demo**</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/lU9iK4/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this would help me to learn better. Regex is my weakness.

Comment: @seoppc You're welcome. Then I only can recommend you https://regex101.com <- It always has a good explanation to the top right, what your current regex does

Answer (score 1):

With out regex:

```
$strng='755 North Estate, NY 11415 (QTY# 34255623)';
$newstr=substr($strng,strpos($strng,"QTY# ")+5,strpos($strng,")");
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex you used `(QTY# (.+)`) will also have QTY# in your match, which is not what you want, based on what you said. "." means anything, "+" is a quantifier, means one or more times, so you want it outside a grouping. If you used /QTY# (.)+/, it would probably work, but return `QTY# 34255623)` and anyhting that follows it

If you want only the digits, you can use `\d` which is the same as `0-9` You can either use what Rizier123 posted and have also the `(QTY#`  part or try using a lookbehind. `(?<=\(QTY\#\s)(\d+)` will return only the number.